# How to saveas a specific spreadsheets in a workbook with multiples spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook with multiples spreadsheets and multiples macros assigned to buttons. Well, one of these buttons is responsible to create a new spreadsheets named "Savings" and saveas this spreadsheets with the suggested name "savings". I would like that when runs the macro pops-up the saveas window and the Field Name suggests "Savings.xlsm". My code to create the "Savings" spreadsheets is working really fine but the Save file is not working, could you guys help me?

```
Private Sub Relatorio_Saving_Click()

  'Code to create the worksheet named "Savings"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Savings" Then 'If Savings exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Disable warnings
            ws.Delete 'Delete Worksheet
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Enable warnings
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws

    'Add Savings Worksheet
    Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.count))
    ws.Name = "Savings"
End With
```

After that there is a lot of codes that work on this worksheet Savings that is not useful for the main purpose.

On the end I have the saveas code, that is not working like I want to:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) 'SaveAs Dialog
    .InitialFileName = "Savings.xlsm" 'Suggested Name
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.count > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs .SelectedItems(1) 'Save File
    End If
End With
```

This code is saving as the whole Workbook, What I want is just to save as the spreadsheets named Savings, and when pops-up the saveas dialog window I want the Save-Astype file shows .xlsm

Comment: ensure the `FileFormat` argument is correct in the `SaveAs` method. If that doesn't work post your specific error *message* (not just the number) and it will help us help you better.

Comment: The SaveAs code above works fine on my setup, perhaps you're attempting to Save without the right permissions etc? Is it overwriting a file (perhaps that's already open?). Provide more detail of the error for clarification.

Comment: the problem with the error 1004 I figured it out, It was happening because  I was trying to save as Excel Workbook, when I changed to  Excel-Macro Enabled Workbook worked really fine. Is there any code that auto-select this option?

Comment: My main problem is, I want to save just one Worksheet, and with this code is saving all the workbook, What I really want is to export this worksheet in a new folder @CLR